# C++ cocos2d-x cannot call protected CCParallaxNode constructor

Tags: android, c++, inheritance, cocos2d-x, protected

Using the tutorial in
http://www.raywenderlich.com/33752/cocos2d-x-tutorial-for-ios-and-android-space-game
for cocos2d-x, I cannot call the CCParallaxNode() constructor from an inheritance.

The inheritance calls in its constructor the constructor of CCParallaxNode

HEADER:

```
class CCParallaxNodeExtras : public CCParallaxNode {

    public :

    // Need to provide a constructor
    CCParallaxNodeExtras();
```

CONSTRUCTOR DEFINITION

```
#include "CCParallaxNodeExtras.h" 

// Need to provide a constructor
CCParallaxNodeExtras::CCParallaxNodeExtras() {
    CCParallaxNode(); // call parent constructor: Cannot be called!
}
```

The error:

```
/home/cocos2d-x-3.0rc0/tests/MyGame/proj.android/../cocos2d/cocos/2d/CCParallaxNode.h: In constructor 'CCParallaxNodeExtras::CCParallaxNodeExtras()':
/home/cocos2d-x-3.0rc0/tests/MyGame/proj.android/../cocos2d/cocos/2d/CCParallaxNode.h:78:5: error: 'cocos2d::ParallaxNode::ParallaxNode()' is protected
     ParallaxNode();
```

It seems that CCParallaxNode() cannot call ParallaxNode() because it is protected. What am I doing wrong here when calling CCParallaxNode()?

Thanks.

Comment: In c++, default constructor is called by inherited constructor by default... so, it's sould be just `CCParallaxNodeExtras::CCParallaxNodeExtras() { }`, it can produce this error

Comment: I then get errors later in the code saying CCParallaxNode is not initialized...

Answer (score 0):

Okay I followed Ray's tutorial and found the solution to the parallaxNode error.

**UPDATED FOR COCOS2DX-3.X VERSION**

In the ParallaxNodeExtras.h, do as follows:

```
#include "cocos2d.h"

USING_NS_CC;

class ParallaxNodeExtras : public ParallaxNode {
    public :
    static ParallaxNodeExtras* create();
    void updatePosition();
} ;
```

Now switch to ParallaxNodeExtras.cpp, and do as follows

```
#include "ParallaxNodeExtras.h"

class PointObject : public Ref
{
public:
    inline void setRation(Point ratio) {_ratio = ratio;}
    inline void setOffset(Point offset) {_offset = offset;}
    inline void setChild(Node *var) {_child = var;}
    inline Point getOffset() const {return _offset;}
    inline Node* getChild() const {return _child;}
private:
    Point _ratio;
    Point _offset;
    Node* _child;
};


ParallaxNodeExtras* ParallaxNodeExtras::create()
{
    // Create an instance of InfiniteParallaxNode
    ParallaxNodeExtras* node = new ParallaxNodeExtras();
    if(node) {
        // Add it to autorelease pool
        node->autorelease();
    } else {
        // Otherwise delete
        delete node;
        node = 0;
    }
    return node;
}

void ParallaxNodeExtras::updatePosition()
{
    int safeOffset = -10;
    // Get visible size
    Size visibleSize = Director::getInstance()->getVisibleSize();
    // 1. For each child of an parallax node
    for(int i = 0; i < _children.size(); i++)
    {
        auto node = _children.at(i);
        // 2. We check whether it is out of the left side of the visible area
       auto offsetx = convertToWorldSpace(node->getPosition()).x;
       auto offsetw = node->getContentSize().width;
       int offsetxw = offsetx + offsetw;
        if(offsetxw < safeOffset)
            // 3. Find PointObject that corresponds to current node
            for(int i = 0; i < _parallaxArray->num; i++)
            {
                auto po = (PointObject*)_parallaxArray->arr[i];
                // If yes increase its current offset on the value of visible width
                if(po->getChild() == node)
                    po->setOffset(po->getOffset() +
                                  Point(visibleSize.width + node->getContentSize().width,0));
            }
    }
}
```

Now in the "HelloWorldScene.cpp" or your GAME_SCENE replace

```
//Create the CCParallaxNode
    _backgroundNode = ParallaxNodeExtras::node();
```

with the following line

```
//Create the CCParallaxNode
    _backgroundNode = ParallaxNodeExtras::create();
```

and the following line in the update function

```
_backgroundNode->incrementOffset(Vec2(2000,0),background);
```

with this line

```
_backgroundNode->updatePosition();
```

P.S. Some of you might need to adjust offset values.

Happy Coding!
Please vote if this solves your problem :)